# Are a data fortress's programs always visible in their cells, or only triggered when a netrunner passes by their cell?

Tags: cyberpunk-2020, netrunner

In all the samples of Netmap, we can see a data fortress with walls, gates, CPUs, memories, and also programs in a determined cell.

Now I wonder, when the netrunner enters in the subgrid and starts to attack the fortress, does he see the programs in a far cell (if visibility is not blocked by an obstacle and withing 20 spaces)?
Or does the map that the netrunner sees not show the location of programs, and will it be up to the referee to decide when a program appear in that determined cell, probably triggered by the netrunner or other programs passing by that cell?

Also, not all programs have "endurance", and they should be deactivated at the end of their action at the end of the turn, so how is possible that a data fortress has all its programs always activated?

So this makes me think that programs are "preassigned" to a cell, but they are like in a sleeping mode, not yet visible...and only after be triggered they appear doing their action.
Can somebody explain how you did in your netrunner mini-games?

Comment: I would like to give an answer, but choose to comment because Cyberpunk2020 is that way, very confusing rules, not clear concepts, and you end house-ruling thins as you see fit, specially when talking about netrunning. The same applies to your other question about stealth (maybe someone gives a good response)

Comment: Yes I know, unfortunately netrunning rules are such confusing. But thank you at least for your comment. The netrunning in Cyberpunk2013 was similar, but the netmap was like a flow charts diagram. So, you could move from one cell to another, and you never knew was was going to wait for you on the next step. But in Cyberpunk2020, the map is a square of 20*20 cells, and since is specified that you can see till 20 cells, you already know what to expect in the next cell.

Comment: By the way @CorvenDallas I wanted to make a software for simulating an incursion inside the Datafortress, and I see in your profile a link about "Quick Netrunning simulator" but the link is broken. Any chance to give a look at it?

Comment: I will search for it, it was old, but my coding skills have improved by then. Anothe thing, I think the Netrunning in the new Cyberpunk Red is going to be somewhat like 2013, get the quickstar rules to get a glimpse.

Comment: Yes, right. it's similar, cause you enter a chamber and have one enemy program to fight. This avoids the confusion they did in Cyberpunk2020,  saying that netrunner can see until 20 spaces and can hit everything he sees. So if a fortress has a program already active in a cell, and this program cannot move, the netrunner can always fight this program from distance or avoid to pass near it since he sees it.

Comment: For this, i wonder that maybe the datafortress that we see in the various manuals, with the icons of programs already in place, maybe it's just for the referee...but the programs will not be visible until triggered by someone passing in their cell. just my guess.
Thank you, let me know if you find. I'm trying to making a videogame using the netrunner mini rules and will be not bad to have some help